# Run python script with ML into C# console app error

Tags: python, c#

I wanna run in C# console app python script with libraries like numpy, pandas, matplotlib.pyplot. If I run simple print('hello world') and save it as test.py it works.

I added to PATH : D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Library\bin but it didn't help me too. Thanks for try helping me!

Code:

```
// full path to .py file
        string pyScriptPath = @"C:\Users\micha\Documents\ML\multipleLinearRegression\multiple_linear_regression.py";

        string outputString = null;
        // create new process start info 
        ProcessStartInfo prcStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
        {
            // full path of the Python interpreter 'python.exe'
            FileName = @"D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe", // string.Format(@"""{0}""", "python.exe"),
            UseShellExecute = false,
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            CreateNoWindow = false,
            Arguments = @"C:\Users\micha\Documents\ML\multipleLinearRegression\multiple_linear_regression.py"
        };

        // start process
        using (Process process = Process.Start(prcStartInfo))
        {
            // read standard output JSON string
            using (StreamReader myStreamReader = process.StandardOutput)
            {
                outputString = myStreamReader.ReadLine();
                process.WaitForExit();
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine(outputString);
```

[console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xFD0z.png)

Comment: Did you try the troubleshooting steps mentioned in the console log error? Please do let us know what was the output.

Comment: outputString = "" in debug, in python script i wrote to test print('hello') than my predict value but it was the same. I checked all steps in the console log error and try fix it to a lot of examples, but no one work with import libraries

Answer (score 0):

You said it works when you run the script with Python. Are you first creating an environment before running it? That may be the issue why it doesn't work when running it from C#.

Comment: Well, I said, that simple python script works in that code, but when i wanna get predict value from my ML model in python script it doesn't work becouse there are import libraries, and there is a problem.